# Custom layout in Android: scrollable graphic with selectable elements over top

Tags: android, layout

I'm fairly new to the Android platform and was wondering if I could get some advice for my current head scratcher:

I'm making an app which in one view will need an image, which can be scrolled on one axis, with a load of selectable points over the top of it.  Each point needs to be positionable on the x and y (unlikely to change once the app is running, but I'll need to fine tune the positions whilst I'm developing it).

I'd like to be able to let the user select each point and have a graphic drawn on the point the user has selected or just draw a graphic on one/more points without user intervention.

I though for the selectable points I could extend the checkbox with a custom image for the selected state - does that sounds right, or is there a better way of doing this?  Is there any thing I can read up on doing this, I can't seem to find anything on the net about replacing the default images?

I was going to use the absolute layout, but see that it's been depreciated and I can't find anything to replace it.

Can anyone give me some code or advice on where to read up on what I need to do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really feels like something you should be doing with the `Canvas` and 2D graphics, rather than trying to twist the widget framework to fit.

Comment: Thank you - will look in to this.  Is this something you've covered in one of your books?

Comment: No, I haven't covered 2D graphics yet. I know that "Hello, Android" by Ed Burnette does.